# what is the best way to secure and maintain a global pip.conf file?

Tags: pip

I am currently trying to set up a global pip.conf file for all users (/etc/pip.conf). However, what is the best way of securing this .conf file such that a user can use the configurations defined inside the .conf file when doing pip installs, but the user is unable to read the contents of the file. This is because I am currently trying to keep some secrets but have no idea how should I tackle it.

Hence, appreciate if anybody can provide some insight on this issue

Comment: I doubt it is possible. `pip config` will probably give out the whole set of configuration options. -- What are you trying to keep secret?

Comment: Absolutely impossible. `pip` needs to read the config file, and if `pip` can read the file so any program can read the file so any user can read the file.